# Execute task after web publish to file system

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I've added the following lines to the publish profile (.pubxml-file):

```
 </PropertyGroup>
   <Target Name="AfterWebPublish" AfterTargets="WebPublish">
     <Message Text="After WebPublish" Importance="high"/>
     <Move SourceFiles="$(publishUrl)\AppSettings.config"  DestinationFiles="$(publishUrl)\AppSettings.new.config"></Move>
     <Move SourceFiles="$(publishUrl)\ConnectionStrings.config" DestinationFiles="$(publishUrl)\ConnectionStrings.new.config"></Move>
   </Target>  
 </Project>
```

After publishing directly from Visual Studio 2015 (Build/Publish...) all files are published BUT NOT RENAMED (moved).

When I use the publish profile in a command line

msbuild /t:WebPublish /p:PublishProfile=%PUBLISH_PROFILE% %PROJECT_FILE%

it works like expected (files published and renamed).

What can I do to execute a task after WebPublish in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Change settings in VS to build with high verbosity and see which targets it executes instead of WebPublish?

Comment: I've changed the settings in VS. The last executed target shown in the VS output window is GatherAllFilesToPublish. When Setting the AfterTargets Attribute from WebPublish to GatherAllFilesToPublish the build fails with error message "Done executing task 'Move' -- FAILED".

Comment: Isn't there more information than just 'ERROR'? Where the files moved succesfully?